# Proof of Baer's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

> **Baer's Theorem:** Let $x$ be a $p$-element of a finite group $G$. Suppose that $\langle x,x^g\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup for every $g\in G$. Then $x\in O_p(G)$.

Here, $O_p(G)$ denotes the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

**My attempt:** Since $\langle x,x^g\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup, it is also nilpotent for all $g\in G$. By definition, all subgroups of a nilpotent group are subnormal. In particular, $\langle x\rangle$ is subnormal in $\langle x,x^g\rangle$ for all $g\in G$. Therefore, by Wielandt's theorem, $\langle x\rangle$ is subnormal in $G$. Also, as $x$ is a $p$-element, $\langle x\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup.

---

I don't know how to proceed from here. To show that $x\in O_p(G)$, I'm left to show that $\langle x\rangle$  is normal in $G$. However, I could only show subnormality.

Comment: Do you think you need that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $G$? For example, what if $G$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven
Because $O_p(G)$ is the largest normal $p$-subgroup, so if $\langle x\rangle$ is normal, it is contained in $O_p(G)$, which would show that $x\in O_p(G)$. If $G$ is a $p$-group, then $O_p(G)=G$ and so $x\in O_p(G)$ is trivial (here, $O_p(G)$ also becomes the largest *subnormal* $p$-subgroup, so there is that).

Comment: My point is, you might not be able to prove that it is normal because there are examples where it is not.

Comment: I see. Then how do I go from subnormality to an element of $O_p(G)$. One can also show that $x$ lies in all Sylow $p$-subgroups. But, I can't see how to use subnormality here.

Comment: Try the case $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $H$, which is normal in $G$ first, i.e., where it is subnormal of length $2$. More generally, does $O_p(G)$ contain all subnormal $p$-subgroups, rather than just all normal $p$-subgroups?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I have tried proving the last part. Can you check the answer I posted?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Wielandt's theorem says that if $H$ is subnormal in $\langle H,H^g\rangle$ for all $g\in G$, then $H$ is even subnormal in $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It suffices to show that $O_p(G)$ is the largest subnormal $p$-subgroup of a group $G$.

So, let $H$ be subnormal in $G$. If $H$ is normal, then we're done. Otherwise, there exists a proper normal subgroup of $K$ of $G$ such that $H$ is subnormal in $K$. Thus, $|K|<|G|$ and so by induction, $H\subseteq O_p(K)$. Now, $O_p(K)$ is characteristic in $K$ which is normal in $G$, so $O_p(K)$ is a $p$-subgroup which is normal in $G$. Thus, $O_p(K)\subseteq O_p(G)$. It follows that $H\subseteq O_p(G)$.

Comment: Seems fine to ne. You have proved that if $H$ is subnormal in $G$ then $O_p(H)\leq O_p(G)$.